# MassTransit Saga RequestActivity can't find correct ConsumeContext

Tags: c#, masstransit, saga

I have a trouble with passing data as event argument to RequestActivity. Here is part of my state machine.

```
public class SampleStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<SampleSaga>
{
    public Event<FirstMessage> FirstEvent { get; private set; }

    public Event<SecondMessage> SecondEvent { get; private set; }

    public Request<SampleSaga, RequestMessage, ResponseMessage> SampleRequest { get; private set; }    

    Initially(When(FirstEvent),
        ThenAsync(context => context.Raise(SecondEvent, new SecondMessage()));
    
    During(
        IntermediateState,
        When(SecondEvent)
            .Request(SampleRequest, context => new RequestMessage(context.Data)) // here throws ArgumentException "The ConsumeContext was not available""
    );
}
```

When RequestActivity.Execute method calls it is trying to get ConsumeContext.
The problem is TryGetPayload(out ConsumeContext <TData> consumeContext) does not get **ConsumeContext<SecondMessage>** because payload cache contains **ConsumeContext<FirstMessage>** instead.

That's why I can't pass SecondMessage to context data of Request unless I make SecondMessage an interface implemented by FirstMessage or make FirstMessage inherit SecondMessage. But it looks like some kind of hack. I also tried to manually add context like Chris Patterson suggested in [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/UakzLmgPecQ) like this.

```
return this.RaiseEvent(context.Instance, SecondEvent, consumeContext);
```

But in my case *consumeContext* must be an RedisSagaConsumeContext<SampleSaga, SecondMessage>, and I have no idea how to initialize it.

Is there any proper way to use a custom model as SecondEvent data and get correct ConsumeContext in RequestActivity?

Comment: A state machine must have a property indicating current state.   I don't see the object.  You have built a transparent latch with no state.

Comment: That's not my full class, it's just sample that shows 2 methods illustrating how request activity is configuring, how event raising and data passing to request. My whole state machine is quite a big to post it here

Comment: State machines are very hard to debug.  I usually start adding debug messages and save into a log file so I can find issues.

Comment: Logging state changes becomes killer feature for me :) For example  
    WhenEnterAny(binder => binder
        .Then(context => _logger.Info($"Document {context.Instance.DocumentId} becomes {context.Instance.CurrentState}.")));

Comment: I usually create a state class with a enumeration for the state and objects as properties enum E_States { STATE_1, STATE_2, STATE_3}; class State { E_States state { get; set;} object instance { get; set;}}